# Ideas for diplaying query results next to buttons

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a temporary table that is created from a series of query with a VBA code. The name and number of fields in the table changes with the results of the queries.
Right now I simply open the table with DoCmd.OpenTable.

What I would like to do is display the table in a form so I can include some buttons for example to allow the user to export the table.

I tried a listbox but the formatting was not good and I can't add horizontal scroll bar to see all fields.

I tried a subform populated from the table, but it would not adapt to the changes of the table (fields and numbers).

Any Idea of what can I do next ?

Comment: Have you tried a [split form](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Create-a-split-form-e8eb0efb-2fa6-4315-9d4b-86e79a1fbe1e)? Or maybe a subform that is actually a form in table view?

Comment: I solved my problem by opening the table in a subform but in a different one than the one the query was made in. That way the subform automatically creates the right fields when the form opens.

Answer (score 0):

the subform seems to be a good idea. When your table is ready to be shown, you can assign it to a subform object via `Me.subFormName.SourceObject = "Table.tableName"`

(of cource "subFormName" and "tableName" have to be replaced by the actual names of the subform and the table)